# SQl guarda datos null

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de guardar datos en mysql pero la variable numero_Dproducto siempre se guarda en null aun que los datos los este recibiendo mediante un array, con la parte de update no tengo problema solamente es en la parte de insertar, quiza sea por el metodo que esta recibiendo este es mi codigo:

por medio de este array extraigo los datos este se genera desde un js, detalles es la variable con la que se genera un proceso de formulas.

```
public function agrega_formula()
  {


    $str = '';
    $detalles = array();
    $detalles = json_decode($_POST['arrayformula']);
    $conectar = parent::conexion();

    foreach ($detalles as $k => $v) {

      $cantidad = $v->cantidad;
      $id_Mprima = $v->id_Mprima;
      $materiales = $v->materiales;
      $unidadm = $v->unidadm;
      $moneda = $v->moneda;
      $precio = $v->precio;
      $importe = $v->importe;
      //$total = $v->total;
      $estado = $v->estado;

      $rinde = $v->rinde;
    $costo = $v->costo;
    $numero_Dproducto = $v->numero_Dproducto;

    $productoc = $v->productoc;
    $categoria = $v->categoria;
    $id_Dproducto = $v->id_Dproducto;
    $id_detalle_Dproducto = $v->id_detalle_Dproducto;
    $id_usuario = $v->id_usuario;
    $id_producto = $v->id_producto;

    $subtotal = $v->subtotal;
    $total = $v->total;
```

```
$stmt = $conectar->prepare("INSERT INTO detalle_Dproducto (id_detalle_Dproducto,numero_Dproducto,productoc,id_Mprima,materiales,unidadm,moneda,precio,cantidad,importe,fecha_Dproducto,id_usuario,id_producto,estado) 
    VALUES (:id_detalle_Dproducto,:numero_Dproducto,:productoc,:id_Mprima,:materiales,:unidadm,:moneda,:precio,:cantidad,:importe,now(),:id_usuario,:id_producto,:estado)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  

numero_Dproducto=:numero_Dproducto,
productoc=:productoc,
id_Mprima=:id_Mprima,
materiales=:materiales,
unidadm=:unidadm,
moneda=:moneda,
precio=:precio,
cantidad=:cantidad,
importe=:importe,
id_usuario=:id_usuario,
id_producto=:id_producto,
estado=:estado");

$stmt->bindParam(':id_detalle_Dproducto', $id_detalle_Dproducto);
$stmt->bindParam(':numero_Dproducto', $numero_Dproducto);
$stmt->bindParam(':productoc', $productoc);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_Mprima', $id_Mprima);
$stmt->bindParam(':materiales', $materiales);
$stmt->bindParam(':unidadm', $unidadm);
$stmt->bindParam(':moneda', $moneda);
$stmt->bindParam(':precio', $precio);
$stmt->bindParam(':cantidad', $cantidad);
$stmt->bindParam(':importe', $importe);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_usuario', $id_usuario);
$stmt->bindparam(':id_producto', $id_producto);
$stmt->bindparam(':estado', $estado);

$stmt->execute();
```

[image: imagen]

Comment: Y en que momento estás validando que ese dato no sea null, o que contenga alguna información ???

Comment: solamente valido el not null desde la base de datos

Comment: la informacion se genera desde un js, desde alli si traen informacion pero cuando llega a este punto, ya no guarda el dato

Comment: si el metodo lo cambio por POST si guarda bien el dato.

Comment: Sin ver cómo recuperas/manejas los datos que pasas en los bindParam poco podremos ayudarte. ¿Qué es `$v`, cómo lo creas, por qué no lo depuras con `var_dump($v);` ?

Comment: ahora les comparto mas codigo

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($detalles);` y analiza la salida. Si no encuentras ahí el motivo del error agrega la salida del  var_dump a la pregunta.

Comment: muestra todos los datos incluyendo la variable numero_Dproducto

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la salida del `var_dump`  a la pregunta para revisarlo?

Comment: claro ahora lo agrego